# How can I split large json file into multiple small chunk files using javascript to display in google map

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I have JSON file of size 200MB.
I want to create a small chunk file and display it in google map (`map.data.loadGeoJson()`)
I am getting `fileName` as comma separated String.

Here's my javascript code:

```
if (parent.getFileName().length > 0) {
    var fileName = parent.getFileName();
    var fileName_array = fileName.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < fileName_array.length; i++) {
        // Trim the excess whitespace.
        fileName_array[i] = fileName_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
        map.data.loadGeoJson(fileName_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://pinetools.com/split-files for split data and you can create multiple files from this link then you can use map.data.loadGeoJson().
also please do defer for the script so a browser will not crash.